# e_magic сигнатура на самом деле ZM а не MZ?

Tags: c++, windows, pe

Пишу такой код(dll библиотека):

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER Doh;
memcpy(&Doh, hModule, sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER));
std::cout << std::hex << Doh.e_magic << std::endl;
```

hModule- это HINSTANCE загруженного модуля(dll).

Выводится не 4d5a а 5a4d при загрузке dll. То есть получается сигнатура e_magic на самом деле равна ZM а не MZ.
А сделано это для того чтоб это читалось как MZ в hex-представлении PE?Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Почитайте про [порядок байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Порядок_байтов). Два последовательных байта соответствующие символам M и Z при прочтении их как короткого int будут поинтерпретированы как число 0x4d5a, потому что используется порядок байт little endian. И наоборот, например, целое число 0x000000ab при записи в файл будет записано как 4 байта: 0xab, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00.

Comment: @insolor я прекрасно знаю про little indian, и вопрос заключается в том,почему изначально в hex представлении эти 2 байта хранятся не в порядке  little endian, а не почему меняется порядок байтов.

Comment: Потому что вы выводите не побайтно, а как число. Попробуйте преобразовать указатель на это поле к `char[2]` и выведите сначала первый, потом второй символ.

Comment: @insolor и правда,получается little indian не работает с char?

Comment: Работает, но char - это один байт, поэтому без разницы в каком направлении этот байт читать.